# What happens to my custom domain email address after website expires?

Tags: domains, email-address, domain-transfer

I'm considering of transferring my domain to another host. I have a custom domain email address(ex. myname@myname.com) which is at the old host.

If I end up transferring my domain to another host will that custom domain email address still work? If I do not transfer my domain or renew it does the custom domain email address not work anymore?

Comment: This question is confusing. Are you transferring the domain name or letting it expire? It is one or the other. It cannot be both. Do not confuse domain registration with hosting. If you transfer your domain to a new host, many hosts can handle e mail for you. Otherwise, you will have to install and configure an SMTP server. I highly recommend finding a host that will handle this for you. Installing your own SMTP server is not recommended for anyone who is not familiar.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was asking what would happen in both scenarios. Would my email address still work with the new host? And If I let the domain expire at the old host, would the email address still work?

Comment: You may still be confusing domain registration and hosting. If the domain name expires, it will not work. If your hosting expires, the domain can still work. You will simply set it up somewhere else. To be clear, what is expiring? If you want to continue using the domain name, it will have to renewed with the registrar. You may have registered your domain name with a web host that is also a registrar. You should be able to renew the domain name without renewing the hosting.

Answer (score 1):

if you had email from like : contact@olddomain.com
And you will have now contact@newdomain.com

To continue receiving email from contact@olddomain.com you need to continue paying for olddomain.com and making a redirection.

Once it's expired you will no more receive email.
It doesn't depend on if the registrar is the same, it just depend on if you still own it and making the right redirection.